# BootStrape Tooltips Change Color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to change the color of the BootStrap tooltips and and make the text to be left aligned. I checked other post, but none of the css changes works for me. I am wondering how to change the css of tooltip text message?

HTML code for tooltips:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info bottom-right-2" data-html="true" 
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="text text">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure there is a space on the left side of the button enough for the tooltip. Otherwise, it will be placed on the right side.

to change the color

```css
/* to change the arrow background */
.tooltip > .arrow:before{
  border-left-color: lightblue;
}

.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  color: darkblue;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

please take a look at bootstrap markup for the tooltip: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/tooltips/#markup

see the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/au4pjwf6/